# python - tempfile and listdir weird behaviour

Tags: python

today I encountered a quite weird behaviour, see this little code snippet:

```
import tempfile
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, abspath

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_folder:
    with open(join(tmp_folder, 'test.pdf'), 'a'):
        pass
    pdfs = [abspath(x) for x in listdir(tmp_folder)] # What the hell happens here?
    print(tmp_folder)
    print(pdfs)
```

Output:

```
> C:\Users\vincenzo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2b5j1yyd
> ['C:\\Users\\vincenzo\\Cloud\\Hobby\\Programmi\\Python\\scripts\\Contabilità\\test.pdf']
```

Can you explain what is happening and how could I get `C:\Users\vincenzo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2b5j1yyd\test.pdf` as I was expecting?

Answer (score 4):

`listdir()` just returns filenames, they don't have a directory prefix. So `abspath()` has no way of knowing that the filenames are from the temporary directory, it returns an absolute path in the current working directory.

Use `join()` to join `tmp_folder` with the filenames.

```
pdfs = [join(tmp_folder, x) for x in listdir(tmp_folder)]
```